# CSS and JS-files repeating themselves

Tags: javascript, asp.net, css, iis, webserver

I have a major problem with my current build. My css and js-files are repeating themselves. Its only one GET from the webserver but the webserver is serving files that are exactly twice as big in size and contains two perfect copies of the css and js-files in one file. 
Im using IIS 7.5. The gzip compression wasnt working either so I turned that off, but still no luck with the repeating-problem.

Im guessing Ive missed out on some key information so just ask and I'll answer as detailed as possible.

Comment: what server side language are you using and how do you include your css and js files?

Comment: C# asp.net, using regular script and link tags. No compression or anything.

Comment: hmmm, I thought you may have been using mvc and may have had a bundling issue.  Not sure what would cause this with normal tags though

Comment: Yeah I dont get it, hours of resultless googling :(